# Visa interview: Will you return to your home country after your studies?

Tags: graduate-admissions, germany, visa

Why almost all students answer 'Yes' to this question? Is this a must for student visa? I have applied to student visa from Iran to study master degree in Germany. I want to pursue PhD (may be in Germany or may be not) and I will apply to work for giant software companies after that.

I don't understand why people write this?

**[UPDATE]**

I will immediately follow PhD after masters either in Germany or somewhere else. Also all students have 18 months job seeking visa extension. Then why should we lie? Embassy definitely knows that everyone will at least give himself a chance to work in a better company.

Comment: If doing a PhD in Germany, do you intend to stay in Germany in the meanwhile between your Master's and your PhD?

Comment: @svavil See update

Comment: Even if you intend to start your PhD as soon as possible, there will likely be a several week-long period when you are neither a Master's nor a PhD. From the point of view of immigration services, you have to return to Iran at this point and apply for another visa to cover your PhD studies.

Comment: @svavil: "you have to return to Iran at this point" - the usual rule that you can stay for up to one more year to possibly find a job does not apply in that case?

Comment: "Why almost all students answer (...)" - could you please clarify what you are basing this statement on? Is there any kind of statistic? Answer, in what context? Even if it is a visa-related thing, students might well give entirely different answers to immigration services (national-protection-oriented bureaucrats who want as few people as possible to stay) and universities (universiy-marketing-oriented bureaucrats who want as many people as possible to successfully transfer from the university to the local industry).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, as far as I understand, you have to file for a residence permit then. IANAL, though, so I'm also waiting for someone to give a complete answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Academia. You would be asked the same question if you apply for visitor (e.g. tourist) visa.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't have any specific statistics. But almost all links I have found in internet that is explaining visa interview, suggest that you should say this to the officer.

Comment: @svavil: According to e.g. [this document](http://www.studienkolleg-hamburg.de/visum/studienabschluss_faq.pdf), at least in Germany, you are supposed to have your student visa converted to a searching-for-a-job visa, which can be used for up to a year or so. While I do not know anyone from Iran, I am in touch with various Asian students (e.g. from China), and from what I have seen there, this conversion is generally done unconditionally (i.e. not comparable to applying for a work visa from abroad, without first graduating in the same country). Furthermore, the student ...

Comment: ... visa remains valid until the end of the semester of the student's last exam, so I'm not even sure there is actually a gap between Master's and PhD.

Comment: @scaaahu, I think part of the academic-specific issue is that kids applying for student visas do not understand what the issue is that generates this question, so they would not understand that the same issue can arise with tourist visas. Indeed, as suggested in the question, many students _do_ specifically want to stay in the country in which they do graduate work, for example, not realizing (perhaps) that the immigration rules try to prevent just that.

Comment: @svavil You are almost with certainty correct. The PhD students at our institute are enrolled at the local university (not to be confused with the institute) only for a brief period, as part of requirements for obtaining the PhD. They all have regular residence permits (if not from the EU), and most, if not on scholarship, have normal employment contracts, like the Germans.

Comment: @paulgarrett That's not academia-specific.

Comment: Depending on the country you are applying to - the visas usually have a "non-immigration" intent clause. If you answer otherwise, you will give them grounds to deny you that visa on your clause. It's sad, but modern systems allow little provision to "grey areas" and by extension honesty in that regard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why almost all students answer 'Yes'?

The host country is not looking to accept immigrants when allowing students to come pursue degrees on education visas.  Each country has their own system, standards and procedures for allowing immigrants in the country, and if you appear like you're trying to skip that by entering as a student they will deny your student visa application.

Comment: Exactly. This may be moderating in the U.S. somewhat in recent years, but under the Bush administration many people had to go to extreme measures to prove that they had powerful motivations to return to their country-of-origin.

Answer (score 4):

You apply for a Study visa for a purpose of studying for a fixed term. This visa does not allow you to stay longer than the term of this study. After the end of your studies you should return to your country (even if your studies are completed or terminated before the expiration of your Study visa).

The question asks you to affirm that you are familiar with the rules and understand it. It does not *really* ask you about you life plans on a general scale (e.g. whether or not you want to apply for a work visa after your PhD or get married or whatnot), and these plans can always change. The question simply aims to establish that you understand that Study Visa has a limited duration, purpose and scope.  That's why most people answer "yes" to this question.

If you decide to overstay your Visa or remain in the country when your studies are completed or terminated, it may be difficult for the government to remove you for the overstay (especially if your visa is still valid - it need to be revoked, you need to be informed, etc). But it it very easy to remove you for lying in your visa application - and the fact that you remain in the country despite staying the opposite in your application can be interpreted as such.  This is (in my opinion) the real purpose of the question.

IANAL.

Answer (score 1):

The bad thing: Your Phd is yet nothing, it is a plan what you say. If you apply for a visa extension because you are a running Phd course, yes that is something.

The students lie because they fear the rejection of their visa. Particularly the USA is infamous in this sense. The German authorities know it very well, more clearly the responsible officers know it, but they follow the directives what they got from the higher levels.

The real effect to the probability of the Visa rejection is probably small, if the student say some different than "yes". Obviously if he states to plan any illegal, that had a very bad effect, but it is unlikely that well-educated people would do that.

However, saying a "yes", on that paper, is practically nothing. Well, you said 5 years before that you plan to go home, however you got a wonderful job offer as a young Master of ..., so you changed your original plans, there is nothing bad in it (and particularly nothing illegal, at least if your employer sponsors your visa).

Note, 5 year is already close to the 8 years where you can apply for citizenship. I do not know the exact rules, but if you are here since 5 years as a student, you are probably close to get at least some "permanent resident" or similar status (meaning that you won't be sent back, except hard cases like being convinced or similar).

In practice, today millions of people live in Germany, with zero German or English skill, with a low-level elementary education, and with zero intention to integrate into the society. The government tolerates it on political reasons.

These directives actually prefer well-educated workforce.

Getting a job after the Masters, yes that will be hard.

Getting the VISA, that is not.

But honestly, also I would say a simple "yes" - simply because it has no relevance for the future.